# Passing dates(variables) between Classes?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to pass variables between classes.
for example:

archive ClassN1.dart
The Class N1 content variable1 = 0

archive ClassN2.dart
the class N2 calculate sumVariables = Variable1 * 2;

For days I've been looking for information about it.
From already thank you very much!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Funtion_Calculate.dart';

class DatesPrincipal extends StatelessWidget {
  get left => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[ //First linea of dates
                NumberDates(),
                StatusNPS(),
                PutDatesNPS()
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberDates extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NumberDatesState createState() => _NumberDatesState();
}

class _NumberDatesState extends State<NumberDates> {

  var adecuado = '0';

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget iconList;
      return iconList = DefaultTextStyle.merge(
      style: descTextStyle,
      child: Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(adecuado,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  ),
                  Text('Adecuado')
                ],
              ),
              width: 100.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The archive number2.dart
- status = adecuado * 2

```
class StatusNPS extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _StatusNPSState createState() => _StatusNPSState();
    }

    class _StatusNPSState extends State<StatusNPS> {

      var status = '82.9'; // status = adecuado * 2

      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Widget iconList;
        return iconList = DefaultTextStyle.merge(
          style: descTextStyle,
          child: Container(
            width: 400.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(status, style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'SF Pro',
                ),),
                Text(' %', style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 65.0,
                  fontFamily:'SF Pro',
                ),)
              ],
            )
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: please post code with proper formatting

Comment: take a look at this post:  https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-communication-between-widgets-f5590230df1e

Comment: put adecuado inside DatesPrincipal class and pass reference to NumberDates & StatusNPS widget